# How do I select a row with most number of minimum values out of each column from a matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 2D list named arr

```
arr=[[0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3],[0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7],[0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.4]]
```

now I want to return a row with most number of minimum values when compared with each column, which in this case would be arr[0].

```
[0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3]
```

How do I do this using pure python or numpy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed number of elements per *sub-list*, we can use NumPy like so -

```
In [53]: arr[np.bincount(np.argmin(arr,axis=0)).argmax()]
Out[53]: [0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3]
```

Alternatively, we can also use SciPy to get the most count step, like so -

```
In [45]: from scipy import stats

In [46]: arr[stats.mode(np.argmin(arr,axis=0))[0][0]]
Out[46]: [0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is definitely cleaner solutions, but this works:

```py
arr=[[0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3],[0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7],[0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.4]]

#list of min count of each array 
counts=[0] * len(arr)
#iterate over all values
for i in range (len(arr[0])):
  minwhere=0 #position min value
  val=arr[0][i] #current min value
  for j in range (1, len(arr)): #iterate over other arrays
    if val > arr[j][i]: #compare for min
      minwhere=j #update index array min
      val=arr[j][i] #update value min
  counts[minwhere]=counts[minwhere]+1 #add one to array with min


print (arr[counts.index(max(counts))]) #get arr with max number of min
```